# Laravel - 1 to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a 1 to many relationship for a certification databse. each emplyee could have several certs, so i would like to show name of the employee when index runs under the Controller. I have 2 models:

- Employee  (holds the list of employees)
- Certs   (Holds the certs with column OWNER that holds the DB if of the employee)

in my Employee model i have (Not every employee has a cert)

```
public function certs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cert');
}
```

in my Cert model I have

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

In my CertsController I have

```
public function index()
 {
     //


     $certs = DB::table('certs')->orderBy('expiresOn', 'asc')->paginate(50);    

     $owner = Cert::with('employee')->get();

     return view('certs.index', compact('certs', 'owner'));
 }
```

in my View I have (in a foreach to show all my certs in order)

```
<small>Belongs to: {{$cert->owner->name}}</small><br>
```

I also tried

```
<small>Expires on: {{$cert->employee->name}}</small><br>
```

They produce the following error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C\resources\views\certs\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

```
$cowner = Cert->employee->get();
```

then in the view

```
  {{$owner->name}}
```

or your way:

```
@foreach($certs->employee as $awardedCert)
     {{$awardedCert->name}}

@endforeach
```

Comment: No mate, that's not the problem, he used custom foreign key name, he should specify which key (in his case he used 'owner') and not employee_id as default

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your eloquent relationship because you have a custom foreign_key attribute (normally laravel will expect `employee_id`), but since you used a custom name (`owner`) then you have to tell laravel that.

```
public function certs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cert','owner','id');
}
```

And inside your template:

```
@foreach($certs as $cert)
  {{$cert->employee->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I did add that, so in my certs i have the owner col witch connects to the 'id' col in the employee table. But now I am getting " Undefined property: stdClass::$owner " - Can you check my View and see if I am calling the variables correctly?

Comment: you have to call it like this `{{$cert->employee->id}}` try that to see if it does output the ID if not then check in the database, maybe that certification doesn't have a valid Employee or the employee of that foreign_key doesn't exist :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. But I am getting this now "Property [employee] does not exist on this collection instance. "

Comment: can you do a `dd($certs);` before `return view('certs.index', compact('certs', 'owner'));`

Comment: check edited answer and did you use id as the primary_key?

Comment: don't you see that he is getting 50 results in that certs variable he is making the call directly on the database; not rederencing the relationship. You can't display those results without iteration. no mate you really can't do it your way.

Comment: yes true, didn't say otherway, below I noted that the problem originally is coming from setting the relatioànships FK, but after that its mandatory to have a loop

Comment: this is the dump:
LengthAwarePaginator {#256 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#249 ▶}
  #perPage: 50
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://xapp.dev/cert"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}

Comment: basically it should work because the collection caries employees there

Comment: @Sletheren but dd($certs); only carries the Certs from the table. i don't have any problem carrying those. it shows 2, which is total number of certs i have stored. what i need to do is take the "owner' col and return the properties of the employee that matches the id

Comment: yes, if you do ( dd($certs[0]->employee); ) you'll find it

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
use App\Certs

public function index()
 {
     $certs = new Certs(); 

     $certs->with('employee')->get()

     return view('certs.index')->with('certs', $certs);
 }
```

and this in view

```
@foreach($certs as $cert)
    {{$cart->employee()->first()->id}} 
    //or 
    {{$cart->employee->id}}

    //if it a oneToMany 
    @foreach($cart->employee as $employee)
        {{employee->id}}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```